# Why are all the images being deleted except for one when I click single delete button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am listing all the images along with delete buttons on side of each image to delete that image, however when I click any delete button, all the images gets deleted except for one. When I console.log() the new array after deletion in arrayRemove() function, it prints the correct array. I am using react framework.

```
{(imageURLs.length !== 0) && (
                  <div>
                    Images
                      {imageURLs.map((img, i) => (
                        <div key={img}>
                            {i + 1 + "."}
                            <img
                              src={img}
                              alt="Images Preview"
                              className="mt-3 mr-2"
                              width="75"
                              height="75"
                              style={{marginLeft: 15}}
                            />

                            <IconButton aria-label="delete"
                                style={{marginLeft: 25}}
                                onClick={() => {arrayRemove(imageURLs, i)}}>
                                <DeleteIcon />
                            </IconButton>
                        </div>
                      ))}
                  </div>
              )
            }
```

This is the arrayRemove function -

```
function arrayRemove(arr, i) {
    if(arr.length === 1) {
        alert("You need to keep atleast one image for your product!")
        return;
    }
    else {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
        setImageURLs((oldArray) => [arr]);
        console.log(imageURLs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `setImageURLs(arr)`? You shouldn't mutate the array though, make a copy with `.slice()` before modifying it.

Comment: setImageURLs(arr) won't update the UI when the image is deleted. Same issue exists even after making a copy with .slice() !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `filter` instead of `splice`:

```
function arrayRemove(arr, i) {
  if (arr.length === 1) {
    alert("You need to keep at least one image for your product!");
  } else {
    const filtered = arr.filter((img, idx) => idx !== i);
    setImageURLs(filtered);
  }
}
```

Using `filter` will avoid mutating the original array, as @Patrick Roberts mentions. Here's a sandbox with a simple working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-easley-7x94b

Comment: For the record, this is functionally equivalent to `const filtered = arr.slice(); filtered.splice(i, 1); setImageURLs(filtered);` as I had suggested in my comment. I guess I wasn't very clear since they seem to have gotten my suggestion wrong.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickRoberts and Eric for the help :) . PS - I understood your suggestion Patrick but somehow it wasn't working for me... It was still deleting all the images except for one when splice was used, it isn't happening when filter is used.